# Background network calls - iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, asynchronous

I need to implement posting some data to a web server in the background. Just to clarify, by "in the background", I don't mean the normal way of showing a spinning icon and posting data to a web service using something like an `AsyncTask` or `ASIHTTPRequest`'s `[request startAsynchronous]` method. I need to maintain a queue of data that a Thread can asychronously start processing and posting to a Web service while the user is working in the application.

I'm looking for some help on designing a queue like that, especially in some edge cases like User receiving a call, logging out of the application while the the post is happening, user leaving the application to goto a different one while a post is happening and the like. How would you handle these cases? Is there any source code you can recommend that does this?

Thanks, 
Teja.

Comment: you should read up on [Grand Central Dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've started using `NSOperationQueue` in my own work lately, for controlling background network requests. `NSOperation` deals with most of the boilerplate code necessary for asynchronously running tasks (such as network operations) on threads in the background (or foreground, if necessary for UI updates).

It also allows dependencies across queues; for example, I use two queues in my application:

The first schedules image downloads, at a max concurrency of 2 at a time, in the background. Each image download has a corresponding completion handler (as an `NSBlockOperation`) that is dependent on the image download completing. These operations sit on the `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]`, which operates on the main thread, allowing them to update UI (specifically, the corresponding `UIImageView`).

Note that `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` are not for network requests only, but any operation that can be divided into atomic tasks and scheduled concurrently.

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW1) are Apple's intro docs on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

Having implemented something similar myself, I would recommend using a service and not a thread to do network calls. That way even if your activity gets killed you're sure your network calls will be executed.

Then to implement the queue i suggest you take a look into IntentService (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

from the docs:

> IntentService is a base class for Services that handle asynchronous
>   requests (expressed as Intents) on demand. Clients send requests
>   through startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as needed,
>   handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself
>   when it runs out of work.
>
> This "work queue processor" pattern is commonly used to offload tasks
>   from an application's main thread. The IntentService class exists to
>   simplify this pattern and take care of the mechanics. To use it,
>   extend IntentService and implement onHandleIntent(Intent).
>   IntentService will receive the Intents, launch a worker thread, and
>   stop the service as appropriate.
>
> All requests are handled on a single worker thread -- they may take as
>   long as necessary (and will not block the application's main loop),
>   but only one request will be processed at a time.

If your application is simple enough you can use sendBroadCast() to share info and notifications between your activity and the IntentService

Comment: Agree, but I need to implement this across iOS, Blackberry and Android and so I was hoping I could avoid services ..

Comment: ok I see your point, I saw that your post title had iOS only until i submitted my answer.

Comment: Android apps are written in Java, while iOS apps are writting in objective-C. I don't think you'll be able to leverage the same code. (I know, the NDK package supports native code in Android.).  This may be best as 3 separate questions.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the same code, Android supports background code execution via services, while iOS and Blackberry don't have a mechanism like that. So I was wondering if it was possible to do without services ..

Comment: Actually it might make it less confusing if I just got rid of Android completely. If it works on iOS, I think I can implement the same on Android without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a singleton that encapsulate a thread :

In the initialisation of your object :

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(mainPosterThread) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

- (void)mainDownloaderThread
{

    if( [NSThread respondsToSelector:@selector(setThreadPriority:)] )
    {
        [NSThread setThreadPriority:0.1];
    }
    NSString *urlToDownload = nil;
    while(shouldRun)
    {
        // Take next data to post in a queue (lastObject of a NSArray for example)
        if( nextDataToPost )
        {
             // Post
        }
        else
        {
             // Sleep for some time.
        }
    }
}
```

You can also have methods for stopping / starting the thread while the app go background / foreground on a multitask supported device. If no multitasking supported, save the post data in the queue at stop time (if not too long) and restore them at start. The biggest chalenge is to manage be able to cancel the current upload while app will ends.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue which I've been perfecting in every new application I write. Basically I wanted network functionality which is asynchronous and which was written by me using native functionality. I'd be happy to show you some of this code if you're interested.

First of all, I suggest that you make all network calls on the main thread **asynchronously** rather than synchronously, using a delegate. This way serialization/synchronization/concurrency is not an issue. And since classes are network delegates, I'd just set up one class to where a new connection has a new delegate instance.

```
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:del] autorelease];

e.g.
    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```