# Nsurlconnection cancels when iPhone screen locked

Tags: iphone, ios, background, nsurlconnection, lockscreen

I have a file which I download with nsurlconnection asynchronously. Everything works fine and I am able to continue the download in the background when the user presses the home button. However if the user locks the screen with the on/off/lock button at the top of the iPhone , the connection is cancelled. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Do you do everything in the same thread? If yes, as far as i know you must use multithreading

Comment: What do you mean by everything? The part where I launch the nsurlconnection request?

Comment: I mean, do you use multithreading or download your files in the the same thread with your app's launch place. Let's say where you launch the NSURLConnection

Comment: I am not using it on a separate thread.. But it is asynchronous.. I tried putting it on a seperate thread but its not calling the delegate methods when it is on a detached thread.. How should I do this?

Comment: As far as i know being asynchronous doesn't mean that the app will run on the background too(I'm not quite sure). Please take a look at this questions&links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861514/background-network-calls-ios, http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/how-to-asynchronously-add-web-content-to-uitableview-in-ios/1732/

Comment: I read the article but I don't find how it relates to my specific issue..

Comment: If you want your connection run even tough eighter your app is in background or the iPhone's screen is locked, you must do that connection in a 'Multithreading' concept. So, they do relate your issue

Comment: @Zigglzworth, I have the same issue. NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005. The most strange thing about this is that app handles background well If user press home button, but works wrong with lock button.