# Receiving reachability notifications while running in the background?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, reachability

I'm having trouble with receiving reachability notifications while running in the background as a location-based reminder app. Has any one succeeded in getting this to work and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to use background task bracketing to get this to work. Reachability needs an active run loop and using a background task seems to be one way to provide this in the background. Not sure if there are other/better solutions for this.

Also if you're using RestKit it already comes with a Reachability Observer which is a modified version of Apple Reachability sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You cant check for network in background, my advice would be the use of Local or Push notifications to bring your app back, then you can check for network status.

Comment: But this is a location-based reminder app and it continues to run in the background. In fact there are a number of apps that run in the background and make network calls.

Comment: You probably is looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861514/background-network-calls-ios

Comment: Alex, please take a look at my answer, that is the way I've got it to work. Also I'm not asking for how to make network calls in the background in this question, but rather what to do in order to receive reachability change notifications in the background. Thanks.